# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list 4

Tags: python, list, int, concatenation, typeerror

I'm required to take a Python module for my course and I get this error for my script. It's plotting the trajectory of a projectile and calculating a few other variables. I've typed the script exactly as in the booklet we are given.
  Because I am an absolute beginner I can't understand other answers to this error. I would appreciate it an awful lot if someone could give me a quick fix, I don't have time at the moment to learn enough to fix it myself.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math # need math module for trigonometric functions

g = 9.81 #gravitational constant
dt = 1e-3 #integration time step (delta t)
v0 = 40 # initial speed at t = 0

angle = math.pi/4 #math.pi = 3.14, launch angle in radians

time = np.arange(0,10,dt) #time axis
vx0 = math.cos(angle)*v0 # starting velocity along x axis
vy0 = math.sin(angle)*v0 # starting velocity along y axis

xa = vx0*time # compute x coordinates
ya = -0.5*g*time**2 + vy0*time # compute y coordinates

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(xa, ya) # plot y versus x
plt.xlabel ("x")
plt.ylabel ("y")
plt.ylim(0, 50)
plt.show()

    def traj(angle, v0): # function for trajectory
        vx0 = math.cos(angle) * v0 # for some launch angle and starting  velocity
    vy0 = math.sin(angle) * v0 # compute x and y component of starting velocity

    x = np.zeros(len(time))   #initialise x and y arrays
    y = np.zeros(len(time))

    x[0], y[0], 0 #projecitle starts at 0,0
    x[1], y[1] = x[0] + vx0 * dt, y[0] + vy0 * dt # second elements of x and
                                              # y are determined by initial 
                                              # velocity
    i = 1
    while y[i] >= 0: # conditional loop continuous until
    # projectile hits ground
        x[i+1] = (2 * x[i] - x[i - 1]) # numerical integration to find x[i + 1]                                       
        y[i+1] = (2 * y[i] - y[i - 1]) - g * dt ** 2 # and y[i + 1]

        i = [i + 1] # increment i for next loop


        x = x[0:i+1] # truncate x and y arrays                                                
        y = y[0:i+1]
        return x, y, (dt*i), x[i] # return x, y, flight time, range of projectile

x, y, duration, distance = traj(angle, v0)
print "Distance:" ,distance
print "Duration:" ,duration

n = 5
angles = np.linspace(0, math.pi/2, n)
maxrange = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):
    x,y, duration, maxrange [i] = traj(angles[i], v0)

angles = angles/2/math.pi*360 #convert rad to degress

print "Optimum angle:", angles[np.where(maxrange==np.max(maxrange))]
```

The error explicitly:

```
  File "C:/Users/***** at *****", line 52, in traj
    x = x[0:i+1] # truncate x and y arrays

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: i = [i + 1] looks "fishy", can you get rid of the square brackets?

Comment: Fix your identation. `i = [i + 1]` you're assigning a list to an int. `x = x[0:i+1]` this looks like it's changing the lists (rather than truncating), I'm betting this is not Python or it's a test for you to find the errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments, this is the offending line

```
i = [i + 1] # increment i for next loop
```

Here, `i` is not actually being incremented as the comment suggests. When `i` is 1, it's being set to `[1 + 1]`, which evaluates to `[2]`, the list containing only the number 2. Remove the brackets.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you for answering and explaining everybody. I can't upvote you atm but I'm sure someone else will :)

Comment: @tglaria it's the one this question is about