# PCA: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pca

I was trying to fit a PCA on my dataset following suggested solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933271/11901732). The code worked for `iris` data of shape `(150, 8)`, which looks like this:

```
array([[ 1.7837721 , -1.23464679,  4.27808537, ...,  0.63061657,
        -1.79849625, -1.41574397],
       [-0.35396307, -0.13400175,  3.91751182, ..., -0.58928302,
        -0.15735542, -0.99157312],
       [-0.20380491, -1.06074392,  4.65814864, ...,  2.19686369,
         0.14920164,  2.33371106],
       ...,
       [-1.05079672,  1.46836264,  5.41970214, ...,  0.32847349,
         0.27133141,  1.01266607],
       [ 0.19569856,  0.57739573,  3.84749973, ...,  0.02400556,
        -0.08193678,  0.51223263],
       [ 0.04905765,  0.66314259,  6.22608157, ...,  0.60076934,
        -0.56890579, -0.23642103]])
```

However, using my data of shape `(3475, 29)` it caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-292-5661ffbde57b> in <module>
     38 # data = array([randn(8) for k in range(150)])
     39 data[:50, 2:4] += 5
---> 40 data[50:, 2:5] += 5
     41 
     42 """ visualize """

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

My data(shape `(3475, 29)`) looks like this:

```
array([[58.5, 27.0, 88.5, ..., nan, 0.0, -3.0],
       [58.5, 27.0, 88.5, ..., nan, 0.0, -3.0],
       [47.0, 45.0, 92.0, ..., 1.6, -0.649519052838329,
        -1.1249999999999998],
       ...,
       [46.0, 44.5, 98.0, ..., 2.5, 0.0, -1.3],
       [46.0, 40.0, 98.0, ..., 2.5, 0.0, -1.3],
       [46.5, 44.5, 76.5, ..., 17.767857142857142, -0.4788774197473401,
        -1.4219984343829701]], dtype=object)
```

Code used:

```
# SO - doug - my data 
from numpy import array, dot, mean, std, empty, argsort
from numpy.linalg import eigh, solve
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show


def cov(X):
    """
    Covariance matrix
    note: specifically for mean-centered data
    note: numpy's `cov` uses N-1 as normalization
    """
    return dot(X.T, X) / X.shape[0]
    # N = data.shape[1]
    # C = empty((N, N))
    # for j in range(N):
    #   C[j, j] = mean(data[:, j] * data[:, j])
    #   for k in range(j + 1, N):
    #       C[j, k] = C[k, j] = mean(data[:, j] * data[:, k])
    # return C

def pca(data, pc_count = None):
    """
    Principal component analysis using eigenvalues
    note: this mean-centers and auto-scales the data (in-place)
    """
    data -= mean(data, 0)
    data /= std(data, 0)
    C = cov(data)
    E, V = eigh(C)
    key = argsort(E)[::-1][:pc_count]
    E, V = E[key], V[:, key]
    U = dot(data, V)  # used to be dot(V.T, data.T).T
    return U, E, V

""" test data """
# data = array([randn(8) for k in range(150)])
data = my_data1   # Using my own data
data[:50, 2:4] += 5
data[50:, 2:5] += 5

""" visualize """
trans = pca(data, 3)[0]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = subplots(1, 2)
ax1.scatter(data[:50, 0], data[:50, 1], c = 'r')
ax1.scatter(data[50:, 0], data[50:, 1], c = 'b')
ax2.scatter(trans[:50, 0], trans[:50, 1], c = 'r')
ax2.scatter(trans[50:, 0], trans[50:, 1], c = 'b')
show()
```

What does

```
data[:50, 2:4] += 5
data[50:, 2:5] += 5
```

do?

I tried to replace these two lines with

```
data = [data[:50, 2:4] += 5]
data = [data[50:, 2:5] += 5]
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297342/11901732), and it returned

```
  File "<ipython-input-296-5d80e1852b4e>", line 42
    data = [data[:50, 2:4] += 5]
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: "What does ... do?"  It adds 5 to every value from 0,2 through 49,3, and also to every value from 50,2 to N,4 where N is the last column.  The implication is that something in that range is not just an integer.  If you didn't know what it does, why would you do it to your data?

Comment: See that `object` dtype?  You don't have a proper 2d numeric array.  It may contain lists, not just numbers

Comment: Hi @Tim thanks, I want to test if it works on my dataset first and refine from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data` is a 2d numeric array,

```
data[:50, 2:4]
```

selects a slice (technically a `view`) of the array, and

```
data[:50, 2:4] += 5
```

adds 5 to all elements of that slice - and modifying `data`.

But

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

means that `data` contains one or more lists, not (just) numbers.  For a list, `+` is not (mathematical) addition, but rather a join/concatenate.  `[1,2,3]+[4]`.

As for your second try:

```
[data[:50, 2:4] += 5]
```

is very different from

```
[i + 1]
```

`[]` makes a list.  You cannot perform assignment, such as `=` or `+=` inside a list.  Hence the syntax error.

The (3475, 29) array that you show lists the `dtype` as `object`.  That's a strong indicator that it contains things other than numbers (or in addition to).  And according to the error, that must be a list(s).

So you need to clean up `mydata`.

Comment: Hi hpaulj, thanks for your answer. But its shape is `(150, 8)`, can it still be `2d`? If it's not `2d`, I guess mine doesn't have to be either? To be honest I'm not sure if I need to modify the data adding 5 to all elements after all. I just want to get the code to work first, and maybe refine it later. With that in mind, what should be my goal when cleaning up my data? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You need to trace back to find how 'data' was created.  If it had been created as a simple array of integers, then you couldn't have one element be a list.  For example `x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,[5,5],6]])` creates a 2x3 array, but because one of the elements is a list, the dtype is object.  That's the kind of thing you have.

Comment: @TimRoberts I get it so the problem is that I had lists instead of floats. Thank you!